# Getting dependency cycle when using michaeltchapman/galera

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, galera

I have installed https://forge.puppet.com/michaeltchapman/galera  and I use in this manifest I wrote like so ...

```
  class { '::galera':
    galera_servers => $galera_servers,
    galera_master  => $galera_master,
    vendor_type    => $vendor_type,
    root_password  => $root_password,
    status_password => $root_password,
  }
```

When I run puppet agent -t on my node I get this error:

```
Error: Could not apply complete catalog: Found 1 dependency cycle:
(Anchor[mysql::server::start] => Package[rsync] => Class[Mysql::Server::Install] => Package[mysql-server] => Class[Mysql::Server::Install] => File[/var/run/mariadb] => Class[Galera::Repo] => Class[Mysql::Server] => Anchor[mysql::server::start])
Cycle graph written to /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state/graphs/cycles.dot.
```

What could be causing this. I assuming my code is so simple that it is not the problem and I also doubt there is a bug in such a widely used module like the galera module.  Can anyone help me out?

Here's what the installed looked like:

```
# puppet module install -d michaeltchapman-galera
Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=3.7.4 (Puppet Enterprise 3.7.2), ruby_version=1.9.3, run_mode=user, default_encoding=UTF-8
Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/production/modules ...
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com ...
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=michaeltchapman-galera&module_groups=base+pe_only
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-stdlib&module_groups=base+pe_only
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-stdlib&module_groups=base+pe_only&limit=20&offset=20
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-stdlib&module_groups=base+pe_only&limit=20&offset=40
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-apt&module_groups=base+pe_only
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-apt&module_groups=base+pe_only&limit=20&offset=20
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-mysql&module_groups=base+pe_only
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-mysql&module_groups=base+pe_only&limit=20&offset=20
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=nanliu-staging&module_groups=base+pe_only
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppet-staging&module_groups=base+pe_only
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=bodepd-create_resources&module_groups=base+pe_only
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-firewall&module_groups=base+pe_only
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-firewall&module_groups=base+pe_only&limit=20&offset=20
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/releases?module=puppetlabs-xinetd&module_groups=base+pe_only
Info: Resolving dependencies ...
Info: Preparing to install ...
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/files/michaeltchapman-galera-0.1.0.tar.gz
Debug: Executing 'gzip -dc /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/puppet-module/cache/michaeltchapman-galera20160720-20773-swxz7d | tar xof -'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type f -exec chmod a-wst {} +'
Debug: Executing 'chown -R 0:0 .'
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/files/puppetlabs-mysql-3.8.0.tar.gz
Debug: Executing 'gzip -dc /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/puppet-module/cache/puppetlabs-mysql20160720-20773-1758gut | tar xof -'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type f -exec chmod a-wst {} +'
Debug: Executing 'chown -R 0:0 .'
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/files/puppet-staging-1.0.7.tar.gz
Debug: Executing 'gzip -dc /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/puppet-module/cache/puppet-staging20160720-20773-7ocepo | tar xof -'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type f -exec chmod a-wst {} +'
Debug: Executing 'chown -R 0:0 .'
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/files/puppetlabs-xinetd-2.0.0.tar.gz
Debug: Executing 'gzip -dc /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/puppet-module/cache/puppetlabs-xinetd20160720-20773-1h85h2q | tar xof -'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type f -exec chmod a-wst {} +'
Debug: Executing 'chown -R 0:0 .'
Debug: HTTP GET https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com/v3/files/puppetlabs-stdlib-4.12.0.tar.gz
Debug: Executing 'gzip -dc /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/puppet-module/cache/puppetlabs-stdlib20160720-20773-xtaaqd | tar xof -'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +'
Debug: Executing 'find . -type f -exec chmod a-wst {} +'
Debug: Executing 'chown -R 0:0 .'
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/production/modules
└─┬ michaeltchapman-galera (v0.1.0)
  ├── puppetlabs-apt (v1.4.2) [/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/core]
  ├── puppetlabs-firewall (v1.7.0) [/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/core]
  ├─┬ puppetlabs-mysql (v3.8.0)
  │ └── puppet-staging (v1.0.7)
  ├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.2.1 -> v4.12.0) [/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/core]
  └── puppetlabs-xinetd (v2.0.0)
```

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using? Can you confirm the $vendor_type that you are passing in?

Comment: My OS is "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)" and I passing 'mariadb' as my vendor_type.

Comment: I just tried the master branch and the dependency cycle error is corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the master branch and the dependency cycle error is corrected.